# McAfee antivirus and File stream SQL Server 2008 R2 Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I am facing file stream issues in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am not able to correlate things and how to fix them.

Below are the event logs. Please let me know if they both the errors (One is Mccafee anti virus and other file stream access issue )are linked to each other.

> Blocked by access protection rule.  Access to object C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MCAFEE\VIRUSSCAN ENTERPRISE\SHSTAT.EXE was blocked by rule Common Standard Protection:Prevent termination of McAfee processes.
>
> Event ID:      5571
> Description:
> Internal FILESTREAM error: failed to access the garbage collection table.